# Subtracting pointers with structure data

Tags: c++, c, address-sanitizer

I found some legacy code and think it has UB in subtracting pointers.
If i right and UB is here - can i find it with ASAN?
I try option -fsanitize=address,pointer-subtract, but it doesn't find problem.

```
g++ -O0 -fsanitize=address,pointer-subtract main.c
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_invalid_pointer_pairs=1 ./a.out
```

Or maybe i mistake and there is no UB?

```
#define ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_1 __attribute__((aligned(1),packed))
typedef struct DAT
{
    unsigned int IP;
    unsigned short port;
} ATTRIBUTE_PACKED_1 Data;

int main(void)
{
    static Data data;
    int diff = ((unsigned char*) &data) - ((unsigned char*) &data.port);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_DATA` This identifier is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of your program will be undefined. You should use another name for the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting pointers to `unsigned char*` for the purpose of accessing raw bytes, and casting pointers for the purpose of performing pointer arithmetic within an object, or an array of objects (in this case, `data` can be treated as an array of 1 `Data` object), are well-defined behaviors in the C and C++ standards.

However, the address of `port` is located after the address of `data` in memory, so your subtraction will result in a negative offset, which may or may not be what you are looking for.  To get the byte offset of `port` within `data`, you would need to subtract the addresses in the opposite order:

```
int offset = ((unsigned char*) &data.port) - ((unsigned char*) &data);
```

Comment: Would like to mention that negative offset is still defined. It is not clear if this is undesired from the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no undefined behavior as related to pointers. You are allowed to cast pointers, and you are also allowed to subtract pointers as long as they point into the same object (due to the fact that an object can be treated as an array of `char`s).

Please note, that this can be replaced with `offsetof` macro and negation of the result.

However, there is undefined behavior as related to names - names beginning with _ (underscore) followed by capital letter are reserved for implementations (in any scope).